# Output buffer length for EVP_DecryptUpdate

Tags: c, openssl

The OpenSSL documentation [says](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_DecryptFinal_ex.html) the output buffer for `EVP_DecryptUpdate` need to be at least `(inl + cipher_block_size)`.

Why is that, when the decrypted plaintext length is shorter than the ciphertext length by 1 to `cipher_block_size` bytes? Is it not sufficient to set the output buffer to be the length of the ciphertext (`inl`)?

Also, does OpenSSL use the buffer during `EVP_DecryptUpdate`? If I set the output buffer to the size of the plaintext, it overruns it. But the returned value for bytes written is less than the size of the buffer.

```
//plaintext = "1234567890123456789\0"

    plaintext = (unsigned char*) malloc(input_len);
    int plaintext_len = 0;
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(de,
                        plaintext, &bytes_written,
                        ciphertext, ciphertext_len)){
        printf("ERROR in EVP_DecryptUpdate\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("bytes_written: %d\n", bytes_written);
    printf("input_len: %d plaintext_len: %ld\n",input_len,strlen(plaintext)+1);

//omitted: EVP_DecryptFinal() which decrypts the rest of the ciphertext
===
bytes_written: 16
input_len: 20 LEN: 20
```

**Update:**
I cloned the openssl github repo and stepped through my test program with a debugger. It seems like this issue was fixed(?) by some change. The previous version of openssl was `1.1.0`, this version is `3.0.0` The buffer is no longer overrun and the value returned in `outl` is the amount actually written to the output buffer.

```
$15 = (unsigned char *) 0x555555595790 "1234567890123456"
(gdb) n
(gdb) p outlint
$16 = 16
(gdb) finish
(gdb) finish
(gdb) x/s plaintext
0x555555595790: "1234567890123456"

//before:
(gdb) x/s plaintext
0x555555559a60: "1234567890123456789"
```

Comment: [The documentation you're referring to](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_DecryptFinal_ex.html) starts out with "For most ciphers ..."  There are exceptions.  Off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure AES/CBC can add `cipher_block_size` bytes instead of `cipher_block_size - 1` bytes.

Comment: Yup, in the case of the input length being a multiple of `cipher_block_size`. Edited the question, as I'm still unsure on the decrypt buffer length.